# TouchImageView Is not Showing Image After Downloading form Volley

Tags: android

```
<com.example.util.TouchImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewRc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:src="@drawable/placeholder_background"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Below is the code where I am wiring this up:

```
private void setImageWithPicaso(String imageUrl) {
    if (!(imageUrl == null)) {
        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(imageUrl).into(imageView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                AppLog.showToastMessage(getActivity(), "Rate Card loading failed!");

            }
        });
    } else {
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        AppLog.showToastMessage(getActivity(), "Rate Card loading failed!");
    }
}
```

The download is happening , and when I start pinching the zoom it works
Appreciate your  time.

Comment: no idea everything works fine

Comment: try to use the background from Picasso while setting the image view

Comment: ok will try to add

Comment: What you mean by after downloading from Volley,Your code shows that u r using picasso for image loading.

Comment: yes the url for loading iam extracting it from json , that's why I wrote the after downloading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(urlToLoad).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_background).into(imageView, new Callback()
 modify with above code and put some pic rename it placeholder_background and put it in drawables

Comment: Thanks its working now,, as soon as progress dialog disables ,able to see the image ,,,thanks

Comment: cheers! buddy you can use some gradient instead of background image